# How to Assign Null or "Empty" Values to Freemarker Time Variables?

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker to build a Liferay Application Display Template. The Template uses a loop to iterate over a Set of Entities (Journal Articles). The Template uses several Variables of Type Date and Time. How may I reset these Variables or check for "empty" in each Iteration of the Loop?

Let's say we have this Code inside the Loop, and it's possible that "starthour" may be empty in some Interations of the Loop:

```
<#assign xPathSelector = saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='start_hour']") />
<#assign starthour = xPathSelector.selectSingleNode(rootElement).getStringValue()?trim />
<#assign xPathSelector = saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='start_minutes']") />
<#assign startminutes = xPathSelector.selectSingleNode(rootElement).getStringValue()?trim />
<#if starthour!="">
  <#assign startTimeString=  starthour +":"+startminutes>
  <#assign starttime = startTimeString?time["HH:mm"]>
<#else>
 <#assign starttime = 0>
</#if>
```

In this Example I've set starttime to 0, but I've also tried to set it as empty String when starthour is empty.

I already tried these Methods to check for the "empty" Variable:

```
<#if (starttime >0) >
<#if starttime.has_content>
<#if starttime!="">
```

I can't check

```
<#if starttime??>
```

after the Variable has once been set in my Loop. Whatever I try I always get Errors like this one, when I use my Script in Liferay:

```
The only legal comparisons are between two numbers, two strings, or two dates.
Left  hand operand is a freemarker.template.SimpleDate
Right hand operand is a freemarker.template.SimpleNumber
```

So how do I "reset" a Time Variable or set an "empty" Value for it, and how to check for an empty (but not Null) Time Value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unset values (and if you could, reading it would fall back to the higher scope, which can later lead to bugs if such variable appears in the data-model). So you either has to introduce a boolean `startTimeSet` variable, or you have to chose a special empty value. As there's no "natural" empty value for time values, you could just use `""` and then before doing anything with it, check the value with `?has_content`.